# SQL Server: Find records with closest Date to CurrentDate based on conditions

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I'm attempting to create a VIEW that would return records based on these conditions:

1. Query needs to retrieve most applicable record based on date
2. For dates that are within an inner Date Range, the closest record to CurrentDate will be returned
3. For dates that are outside an inner Date Range, the closest record to CurrentDate will be returned

Sample tables in the database:

**Person** table:

```
pId     | Name
----------------------
01      | Person 1
02      | Person 2
----------------------
```

**PersonDate** table:

```
dId     |  pId      | StartDate     | EndDate
---------------------------------------------------
A1      |   01      |   2014-01-08  |   2018-01-08  
A2      |   01      |   2016-11-23  |   2016-12-01  
A3      |   01      |   2016-12-03  |   2016-12-08
A4      |   02      |   2016-10-10  |   2016-12-31
A5      |   02      |   2016-12-01  |   2016-12-05
```

If I run this query and the `CurrentDate` is 2016-11-28:

```
select p.name, d.startdate, d.enddate
from Person p, PersonDate d
where p.pId = d.pId
and d.StartDate = (select max(sl.StartDate)
                   from PersonDate sl
                   where d.pId = s1.pId)
```

The records that are returned are:

```
name        | startdate     | enddate
-------------------------------------------
Person 1    |   2016-12-03  |   2016-12-08      --> PersonDate Table row A3
Person 2    |   2016-12-01  |   2016-12-05      --> PersonDate Table row A5
-------------------------------------------
```

Both returned records are incorrect based on the conditions I'm trying to get back. I understand why I'm getting the returned records, and it is due to using the Max() function within my subquery, but I don't know how to write the query/subquery.

The correct records that I want to be return are (CurrentDate being 2016-11-28):

```
name        | startdate     | enddate
-------------------------------------------
Person 1    |   2016-11-23  |   2016-12-01
Person 2    |   2016-10-10  |   2016-12-31
-------------------------------------------
```

- `PersonDate` table row A2, since this inner Date Range falls closest to `CurrentDate` (condition #2)
- `PersonDate` table row A4, since the inner Date Range (A5) hasn't come yet (condition #3)

When `CurrentDate` is 2016-12-02:

```
name        | startdate     | enddate
---------------------------------------------
Person 1    |   2014-01-08  |   2018-01-08  
Person 2    |   2016-12-01  |   2016-12-05
---------------------------------------------
```

- `PersonDate` table row A1, since `CurrentDate` is outside both row A2 and A3 inner Date Ranges
- `PersonDate` table row A5, since `CurrentDate` is inside a Date Range

How can I write a VIEW that would return records based on the conditions above?

Comment: Don't conditions 2 and 3 above have the same outcome (the closest record to CurrentDate will be returned)?

Comment: By "inner date range" do you mean the start date to end date range of each record?

Comment: Very well written question. In your sample data, it seems to me that A4 is just condition 2 as well since it's inside the date range? The solution to finding a 'closest' date is to find the difference in days between 2 dates then use `ABS` to remove negatives, and find the smallest number.

Comment: No, Condition 2 is based on inner Date Ranges and Condition 3 is based on not being inside any inner Date Ranges...I had a hard time figuring out how to describe this.  If you look at the PersonDate Table:  CGritton: A1 is the main Date Range, A2 & A3 are the inner Date Ranges for Person 1.  Condition 2 is met if CurrentDate is inside A2 or A3, Condition 3 is met if Current Date isn't inside A2 or A3.  Hope that clears that up.  The last 2 examples should help explain the 2 conditions.

Comment: Nick McDermaid:  A4 is the main Date Range for Person 2, A5 is the inner Date Range for Person 2.

CGritton:  "Inner Date Range" is the sub-Date Range for the main Date Range.   A1 and A4 are the Main Date Range, while A2, A3, A5 are sub-Date Ranges to their respective Person object.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why some records are called 'inner date range' and some aren't. Is this a flag on the record? I just see a bunch of records with date ranges but no way to differentiate what is 'inner' and what isn't.

Comment: Oh I see - they aren't mutually exclusive date ranges. Some are inside others. Can there ever be any overlapping, or are they always inside?

Comment: Nick.McDermaid:  I made up the term "inner date range" - I'm bad at explanations.  It's a parent and child table setup where Person is the Parent Table and PersonDate is the Child Table. It's a 1 to Many Relationship (tied by the pId attribute column in each Table).   The theory is that there should never be any overlapping of Date Ranges per Person's data object.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #temp(did varchar(10),pid int,startdate datetime,enddate datetime)

insert into #temp values('A1',01,'2014-01-08','2018-01-08')
insert into #temp values('A2',01,  '2016-11-23'  ,   '2016-12-01'   )
insert into #temp values('A3',01, '2016-12-03'  ,   '2016-12-08'  )
insert into #temp values('A4',02,  '2016-10-10'  ,   '2016-12-31'  )
insert into #temp values('A5',02, '2016-12-01'  ,   '2016-12-05'  )


select b.pid,b.startdate,b.enddate
from
(
select ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by pid order by id desc) as SID , a.*
from
(
select 
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by pid order by startdate,enddate desc) as ID
, * from #temp 
--to identify whether it is inner or outer
--1 means outer
--2 means inner
)a
where '2016-12-02' between startdate and enddate
--to find date lies in outer or inner range and select the required
)b
where b.SID=1
```

Comment: Mani:  Thank you, this worked with some very minor modifications to fit my database needs.