# Create an indicator using first record of each policy and subsequent transactions within 90 days from original

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, window-functions

TL/DR: There are many transaction types for each policy, all start with an "N" as this is the new business transaction. R = Renewal and usually follow each year. A "C" means the policy was cancelled, and a "U" means it was reinstated, thus undoing the cancellation. I need to know if, for each policy, within 90 days of the N record the business cancelled (0) or was held via no cancellation or undo-ing of a cancellation which also occurred within that 90 day window (1).

VERY similar question to this one:
[SQL Server: Find records with closest Date to CurrentDate based on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835873/sql-server-find-records-with-closest-date-to-currentdate-based-on-conditions/40839276#40839276)

My data would look like this, for 4 policies (ID).

```
Trs | Id | Effective_Dt  | Expiration_DT
N      |   01      |   2018-01-08 | 2018-01-23
C      |   01      |   2018-01-23 | 2018-02-03 
U      |   01      |   2018-02-03 | 2019-01-08 
R      |   01      |   2019-01-08 | 2020-01-08
R      |   01      |   2020-01-08 | 2021-01-08
N      |   02      |   2019-10-10 | 2019-12-01
C      |   02      |   2019-12-01 | NULL
N      |   03      |   2017-06-10 | 2017-11-01
C      |   03      |   2017-11-01 | NULL
N      |   04      |   2017-06-10 |   2017-07-01
C      |   04      |   2017-07-01 |   2017-11-01
U      |   04      |   2017-11-01 |   NULL
```

each record is a new transaction within a policy, where N=new business written, C = Canceled, U=Reinstated (undo cancel), R = renewal

The expiration date is usually 1 year from the effective date for renewals, but in the case when a cancellation happens the expiration date is the effective date of the new transaction.

For this ask I'm specifically concerned with N, C and U transactions; but I included R so you get a sense of what the data looks like. What I need to know, is which policies (0 if canceled or 1 indicator if retained) had a C transaction type within 90 days of their N transaction type... and were NOT followed by a U within that same period.

Example / Outcome:

```
Id      |   Retained      
01      |     1    
02      |     0 
03      |     1   
04      |     0
```

Details:

- For policy 01 the N occurs on 2018-01-08. 90 days from this would be 2018-04-08. The C record on 2018-01-23 was undone on 2018-02-03; which falls within the 90 day range. So this policy would get a 1 for being retained.
- Policy 02 the N occurs on 2019-10-10. 90 days from this would be 2020-01-08. The C record on 2019-12-01 was not undone. So this policy would get a 0 for being canceled.
- Policy 03 the N occurs on 2017-06-10. The C record on 2017-11-01 happened after the 90 day. So this policy would get a 1 being retained.
- Policy 04 the N occurs on 2017-06-10. The C record on 2017-07-01 happened before the 90 day, and was then undone on 2017-11-01-- but this is after the 90 days. So this policy would get a 0.

I hope this isn't too poorly asked... but basically taking the date of the N transaction for each policy, comparing it to the last U or C transaction that occurred within 90 days of the N. If it is a C, 0, else a 1.

Comment: What if there are two N for a given policy?

Comment: If everything else is replicable, use `dateadd` function with a correlated subquery to create the expiration column "dynamically"

Comment: Always its better to give explanation in short and make use of desired output based on sample input. Sometimes, desired output with given input sample is self explanatory

Comment: @GMB there can't be-- I'm dealing with insurance policies. when a quote is written into a policy, it becomes an N. once it is an N, it can be canceled, and reinstated but a policy is never 'new' again, so there'd never be two N's for one policy. does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer figured out... created a CTE :

```
 NB_CANCELS AS (
 SELECT 
 CONCAT(POL_SYMBOL_CD,POL_NBR) NB_CANCEL_ID
,EFFECTIVE_DT
,EFFECTIVE_TYPE_CD
,HISTORY_VLD_NBR
,PLN_EXP_DT
,EXPIRATION_TYPE_CD
,EXPIRATION_DT


 FROM  (SELECT *,(SELECT DATEADD(D,90,OGN_EFF_DT) -- Find NB record and add 90 Days
                FROM  Exceed_Reporting.XCD.POLICY_TAB SUB
               WHERE  SUB.EFFECTIVE_TYPE_CD='N' --- NB only 
               AND    (SUB.EXPIRATION_TYPE_CD!='7' OR EXPIRATION_TYPE_CD IS NULL)
               AND    SUB.POLICY_ID           = PT.POLICY_ID
               AND    SUB.QUOTE_SEQUENCE_NBR   = 0
              ) NB90DAY
              FROM Exceed_Reporting.XCD.POLICY_TAB pt) PT1
 WHERE EFFECTIVE_TYPE_CD in ('5','3','s','p') -- Any cancel status
AND (EXPIRATION_TYPE_CD!='7' OR EXPIRATION_TYPE_CD IS NULL)
AND POL_SYMBOL_CD in ('HO','DP')
AND RIGHT(policy_ID,4)!='SAVE' 
AND STATUS_CD='A' 
AND pt1.EFFECTIVE_DT<=NB90DAY
AND (pt1.EXPIRATION_DT>=NB90DAY
OR PT1.EXPIRATION_DT IS NULL)
,
```

then in my base query, created the following Case statement:

```
 , CASE     WHEN pt.EFFECTIVE_TYPE_CD!='N' THEN NULL
            WHEN CONCAT(PT.POL_SYMBOL_CD,PT.POL_NBR) IN (SELECT NB.NB_CANCEL_ID FROM NB_CANCELS nb)
            THEN 0  
            else 1 
END AS NB_90D_PERSISTENCE  



        FROM (SELECT *,DATEADD(dd,90,EFFECTIVE_DT) NB_90DAY
                    FROM POLICY_TAB 
                where    EFFECTIVE_TYPE_CD in ('N','R')

                ) PT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works for you

```
  Select id,
   max(Case when  trs='C' and
      Expiration_DT<=min(Effective_Dt) 
      +90
    Then 1 else 0 end) as indicator
    from table  
   group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions in two steps: first get the date of the first 'N' per policy with a window `min()`, then do a conditional `last_value()` to recover the type of the last U or C transaction.

```
select distinct 
    id,
    case 
        last_value(
            case 
                when coalesce(expiration_dt, effective_dt) <= dateadd(day, 90, n_effective_dt)
                and trs in ('C', 'U')
            then trs
            end
        ) over(partition by id order by effective_dt)
        when 'U' then 1
        when 'C' then 0
    end retained
from (
    select
        t.*,
        min(case when trs = 'N' then effective_dt end) over(partition by id) n_effective_dt
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: Still learning how to use stack overflow -- i'm on MS Sql Server 2016.